# Prove that sequence of real numbers $(d(x_n,p))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

be $M$ a metric space. if a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_n=p$. Prove that sequence of real numbers $(d(x_n,p))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$

I have tried to use the following the way, however I do not know if I am in the way direction. Could someone help me?

If $x_n\rightarrow p, y$ then $d(p, y) ≤ d(p, x_n) + d(x_n , y)\rightarrow 0.$
So $d(p, y) = 0$, implying that $p = y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=p$ means that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists N\in\Bbb N):n\geqslant N\implies d(x_n,p)<\varepsilon$$and asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,p)=0$ in $\Bbb R$ means that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists N\in\Bbb N):n\geqslant N\implies|d(x_n,p)|<\varepsilon.$$It's not that much different, right?!

Comment: A.k.a. it is the very definition, to complete this answer :)

Comment: Right, José Carlos Santos!!

Comment: @AndrewFernand If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer « per se ». But should be useful for you to think about the topic.

**How do you define $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n=p$?**

Comment: To me it "sounds" like an answer.